# Generic Set/Array Initialization - Java

Tags: java, data-structures, set

I am trying to fulfill this interface

```
Set<T> filter(UnaryRelation<T> x)
```

I need to create a set containing elements in a set that satisfy x. I can't seem to figure out how to initialize the set being that it is said to be generic. How can I create it so it is not generic?

```
Set<T> filteredArray =  new Object<T>[size()];
```

Comment: `new Set<T>()` should work, right? Maybe I don't understand your question...

Comment: Put simply, I need to create/return a set that is of type Set<T>. I don't know how to do that when Java does not allow me to create something generic or abstract

Comment: you can initialize HashSet instead of Set. Set<T> filteredArray = new HashSet<T>

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide what `T` is when you invoke that code. For example:

```
class Test<T> {

    private Set<T> filter;

    public Test() {
        filter = new HashSet<T>();
    }

    public Set<T> getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test<Integer> test = new Test<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> filter = test.getFilter();
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html